different behaving of ligaturing callback with LaTeX
I am trying to reproduce the TeX following example (Paul Isambert, TUGboat,https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-1/tb100isambert.pdf):
\directlua{
local GLYF = node.id("glyph")
function show_nodes (head)
local nodes = ""
for item in node.traverse(head) do
local i = item.id
if i == GLYF then
i = unicode.utf8.char(item.char)
end
nodes = nodes .. i .. " "
end
texio.write_nl(nodes)
end

callback.register("ligaturing",
function (head, tail)
node.ligaturing(head)
show_nodes(head)
end)

}

Your office
\end.

but with (Lua)LaTeX. Unfortunately, the following code does not give the right output 41 9 0 Y o u r 12 o 7 c e 12 but 41 9 0 Y o u r 12 o f 7 f i c e:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}

\luadirect{
    local GLYF = node.id("glyph")
function show_nodes (head)
local nodes = ""
for item in node.traverse(head) do
local i = item.id
if i == GLYF then
i = unicode.utf8.char(item.char)
end
nodes = nodes .. i .. " "
end
texio.write_nl(nodes)
end
}

\begin{luacode}
    function mylig(head, tail)
    node.ligaturing(head)
    show_nodes(head)
    end
\end{luacode}
\luadirect{
    luatexbase.add_to_callback("ligaturing",mylig,"My Ligaturing")
}

Your office
\end{document}

Any explanation?
Thanks in advance.

Thanks. However, luahbtex Version 1.18.0 (TeX Live 2024)  gives the output 41 9 0 Y o u r 12 o 7 c e 12 whereas lualatex (with luahbtex) with my code gives 41 9 0 Y o u r 12 o f 7 f i c e.

LuaLaTeX uses an OpenType font by default, they are shaped with different code and not with node.ligaturing. So unless you explicitly switch to an old font node.ligaturing is mostly a noop (and the ligaturing callback generally not very useful). There are a few exceptions where node.ligaturing does something for OpenType fonts, but that's mostly in base mode which shouldn't be used for normal text.

Ok thank you for the explanation!

Maybe, you can transform your comment as an answer for closing the post?

And how can I use the same T1 CM font with lualatex? I tried \fontencoding{T1} without success.

Here is the code that solves the problem thanks to Marcel Krüger.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\luadirect{
    local GLYF = node.id("glyph")
function show_nodes (head)
local nodes = ""
for item in node.traverse(head) do
local i = item.id
if i == GLYF then
i = unicode.utf8.char(item.char)
end
nodes = nodes .. i .. " "
end
texio.write_nl(nodes)
end
}

\begin{luacode}
    function mylig(head, tail)
    node.kerning(head)
    show_nodes(head)
    end
\end{luacode}
\luadirect{
    luatexbase.add_to_callback("kerning",mylig,"My Ligaturing")
}

Your office
\end{document}

